# Session Cookie Path is Not Set

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am trying to set Session Cookie Path in ASP.NET `Global.asax` File inside `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` Method. but it is not working.

I Need to Set Session Cookie Path to Specific Application Folder. So if another application is hosted then both application path will be different.

Comment: have you solved this one? i'm having the same issue